# Electrode Native combine miniapps

Tags: react-native, walmart-electrode, electrode-native

How do I combine two react native miniapps created with electrode native?

I have a host application (miniapp) create in electrode native, say MovieListMiniApp (copied from electrode native samples) and another electrode native miniapp, say MovieDetailsMiniApp.

I can run both the miniapps independently but would now like to run MovieDetailsMiniApp inside host miniapp (MobileListMiniApp).

I followed the steps outlined here: https://github.com/electrode-io/movielist-miniapp#run-the-app-with-moviedetailsminiapp but that does not work on my mac.
I get below error.  How to fix this problem and get this to work?

```
✖ An error occurred: Command failed: /Users/paveen/.ern/versions/0.41.6/node_modules/ern-core/node_modules/.bin/r
eact-native bundle --entry-file=index.ios.js --dev=false --platform=ios --bundle-output=/Users/praveen/.ern/contai
nergen/out/ios/ElectrodeContainer/Libraries/MiniApp/MiniApp.jsbundle --assets-dest=/Users/praveen/.ern/containerge
n/out/ios/ElectrodeContainer/Libraries/MiniApp
✖ error Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `../../../../../../../Users/praveen/Documents/SampleApps/react-native/electrodeMiniAppSample/MovieListMiniApp/index.ios.js`: @babel/runtime/hel
pers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project.
```